# how to access files in apple photostream

Tags: objective-c, icloud

I was wondering if there is a way to access the files stored in Apples Photostream via code from another Application. I haven't found anything online yet concerning that topic and don't know if it's even possible.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this example:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MyImagePicker/Introduction/Intro.html

The key thing to remember is to use the ALAssetsGroupPhotoStream flag when specifying the values for enumerateGroupsWithTypes.